# capture events from two different modules

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to break my shiny app in to modules. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

testModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
        checkboxInput(inputId = ns("select_dynamic_date_range"),
                      label = "enable date range",
                      value = FALSE,
                      width = NULL),

        uiOutput(outputId = ns("dynamic_date_range_ui"))
  )
}


testModulePlotOutput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
        plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("distPlot"))
  )
}



testModule <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
        # PRINT TO CONSOLE
        print(paste("dynamic_date_range:", input$dynamic_date_range));
        print(paste("select_dynamic_date_range:", input$select_dynamic_date_range));


        df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)
        p <- ggplot (df, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point()
        ggplotly(p)
    });


    output$dynamic_date_range_ui <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(input$select_dynamic_date_range)){
        return();
      }

      if (input$select_dynamic_date_range){
        dateRangeInput(inputId = "dynamic_date_range",
                        label = "date range:",
                        start = Sys.Date() - 1,
                        end = Sys.Date() + 2)
      }
      else{
        return();
      }
    });
}



# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
        testModuleUI("class")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
        # plotlyOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        testModulePlotOutput("class")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(testModule, "class")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My goal is to dynamically (based on **checkboxInput** element) create **dateRangeInput** element and then use value from this **dateRangeInput** during plot creation (This is just an simplified example so I do not really use the **dateRangeInput** during plot creation but the first thing I really need is to pass the value from **dateRangeInput** to **renderPlotly** function). I did similar thing [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930466/server-function-called-twice-for-one-change-in-user-interface) and it worked fine. One problem that I have here is that the variable **dynamic_date_range** never gets proper values from **dateRangeInput** element. If I understand the philosophy of shiny and modules correctly then the problem is that I have two elements with same ID: **testModuleUI** and
**testModulePlotOutput**, (both have ID name **class**). I've been thinking about different class name for one of elements but is it possible to correctly use **callModule** function in this case? Is it even possible in shiny modules to capture events from two different modules? Or is this completely wrong approach and the module design should be different? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `renderUI` inside a shiny module, you will have to pass the namespace function `ns` explicitly like this to make sure the created `HTML` element uses the module prefix.

```
output$dynamic_date_range_ui <- renderUI({
  req(input$select_dynamic_date_range)
  dateRangeInput(inputId = session$ns("dynamic_date_range"),  ## add ns here
                 label = "date range:",
                 start = Sys.Date() - 1,
                 end = Sys.Date() + 2)
});
```

This behavior is documented in the [shiny modules article on rsudio.com](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

> Inside of a module, you may want to use uiOutput/renderUI. If your renderUI block itself contains inputs/outputs, you need to use ns() to wrap your ID arguments,

With this change, the app  seems to work as expected now.

Having two different UI parts on the same module is not a problem as long as there are no name collusions (for example, if you use `ns("plot")` in both). I use that quite often for modules with a default UI and a secondary optional UI: a "details view" for example. See [here](https://github.com/statistikat/codeModules/blob/master/R/variableView.R#L234) for an example.

### Sidenote

From a conceptual standpoint, I would suggest you should use `shinyjs::show` and `shinyjs::hide` (or `conditionalPanel`) instead of `renderUI` in this case to update the element in the existing DOM. This is also more convenient to use inside modules because unlike `renderUI`, the `show/hide` functions respect namespaces by default. Here is an example

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

testModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput(
      inputId = ns("select_dynamic_date_range"),
      label = "enable date range",
      value = FALSE,
      width = NULL
    ),
    hidden(dateRangeInput(
      inputId = ns("dynamic_date_range"),
      label = "date range:",
      start = Sys.Date() - 1,
      end = Sys.Date() + 2
    ))
  )
}

testModulePlotOutput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("distPlot"))
  )
}

testModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$select_dynamic_date_range, {
    switch(
      input$select_dynamic_date_range + 1,
      hide("dynamic_date_range"),
      show("dynamic_date_range")
    )
  })

  dateRange <- reactive({
    switch(
      input$select_dynamic_date_range + 1,
      input$dynamic_date_range,
      "daterange not in use"
    )
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    # PRINT TO CONSOLE
    print(paste("dynamic_date_range:", dateRange()));
    print(paste("select_dynamic_date_range:", input$select_dynamic_date_range));

    df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)
    ggplot (df, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point()
  });
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      testModuleUI("class")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      testModulePlotOutput("class")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(testModule, "class")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```